# Oracle SQL setting the primary and foreign key with constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE DriverTest
            (DTest_ID number(8),
            DTest_Type varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
            DTest_Date date NOT NULL,
            DTest_Result varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT pk_DTestID PRIMARY KEY(DTest_ID));
            CONSTRAINT fk_EmployeeData FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES (Employee_ID));

CREATE TABLE Employee
        (Employee_ID number(8),
        Em_Name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
        Em_Address varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
        Home_no number(15) NOT NULL,
        Em_no varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
        DoB date NOT NULL,
        Gender  varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
        NI_no number(10) NOT NULL,
        Annual_Salary number(10) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT pk_EmployeeID PRIMARY KEY(Employee_ID));
```

Why won't this execute? It worked with my first two table for customer to hiring, but employee to driver, it says:

> 'Employee_ID' invalid indentifier, ORA-00904 and 00904 00000 - Invalid
>   identifier

I thought I declared the primary and foreign? May I please have some help, I've looked at similar enquire, but they all have the same script as mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d81320c6933dcfbcfdb0df6380d2686c) is a working version in db<>fiddle.

Some of the issues:

- The `Employees` table needs to be defined *before* it can be used in a foreign key relationship.  Hence, the tables are in the wrong order.
- A column used in a foreign key needs to be declared.  So, `EmployeeId` needs to be declared in `DriverTests`.
- You have an extra paren and semicolon in the second table definition.

I changed the names of the tables to be plural, because that is how I would name them.

The working code is:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
        Employee_ID number(8),
        Em_Name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
        Em_Address varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
        Home_no number(15) NOT NULL,
        Em_no varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
        DoB date NOT NULL,
        Gender varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
        NI_no number(10) NOT NULL,
        Annual_Salary number(10) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT pk_EmployeeID PRIMARY KEY(Employee_ID)
 );

CREATE TABLE DriverTests (
        DTest_ID number(8),
        Employee_ID number(8),
        DTest_Type varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
        DTest_Date date NOT NULL,
        DTest_Result varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT pk_DTestID PRIMARY KEY (DTest_ID),
        CONSTRAINT fk_EmployeeData FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES Employees(Employee_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your create table ordering is incorrect. Need to create Employee table first:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
    (Employee_ID number(8),
    Em_Name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
    Em_Address varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
    Home_no number(15) NOT NULL,
    Em_no varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    DoB date NOT NULL,
    Gender  varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
    NI_no number(10) NOT NULL,
    Annual_Salary number(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_EmployeeID PRIMARY KEY(Employee_ID)); 

CREATE TABLE DriverTest
        (DTest_ID number(8),
        DTest_Type varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
        DTest_Date date NOT NULL,
        DTest_Result varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT pk_DTestID PRIMARY KEY(DTest_ID));
        CONSTRAINT fk_EmployeeData FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES (Employee_ID));
```